# Php - Session Variables

Tags: php, session, session-variables

I'm trying to make an admin panel for my website. I want to check the permission from the current logged in user, when not enough permission redirect.

I tried allot of things but i can't get it working!
This shows up when i echo all the session variables with this code:

```
echo '<pre>';
var_dump($_SESSION);
echo '</pre>';
```

This shows up:

```
array(2) {
   ["usr_id"]=>
   string(1) "1"
   ["usr_name"]=>
   string(13) "rombie18"
}
```

Now i want to get permission from the session variable and check if the permission is high enough.

I want to get this:

```
array(2) {
   ["usr_id"]=>
   string(1) "1"
   ["usr_name"]=>
   string(13) "rombie18"
   ["usr_permission"]=>
   string(13) "admin"
}
```

And check permission:

```
if(!$_SESSION['permission'] == 'admin') {
    //redirect
    exit();
}else{
    //do something here.
}
```

Comment: And what is the problem?

Comment: I think it should be `$_SESSION['usr_permission']` instead of `$_SESSION['permission']`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> At first you have to assign your required information in `$_SESSION`
>   variable while login process execute.

**Example: Login process (define `usr_permission`)**

```
$result = mysqli_query(..........); //Your user chhecking query
//check if found in data_base by userId and Pass.
$_SESSION["usr_id"]        = $result[0]['usr_id']; //assign usr_id 
$_SESSION["usr_name"]      = $result[0]['usr_name']; //assign usr_name
$_SESSION["usr_permission"]= $result[0]['usr_permission']; //assign usr_permission
```

**Example: Check permission by `$_SESSION['usr_permission']`**

```
if(!$_SESSION['usr_permission'] == 'admin') {  //here user same variable name
    //redirect
    exit();
}else{
    //do something here.
}
```

---

> You have made 2 mistake: you don't assign
>   `$_SESSION["usr_permission"]` and checking by undefined variable
>   `$_SESSION['permission']`

Answer (score 0):

According to your code, you should use `$_SESSION['usr_permission']` instead of `$_SESSION['permission']`